# Will Azure storage account prices per account or will it be single price and can create multiple storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have azure account - I have question is that if I create two storage account then do I need to pay for both this account or If I have Azure account then I can create as many as storage account I want with single price?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure pricing question (and storage pricing is clearly documented on the Azure site). Not a programming question.

Comment: David there is no any clarification there with multiple storage accounts

Comment: Why should there need to be? Pricing is clearly based on consumption. There is nothing stating *anything* about paying for a storage account itself.

Comment: Yes but it should stated there like this as well that it is not based on account but it only based on consumption, they just wrote the based on consumption but not wrote about the account may be if we create multiple account there will be minimal charges there or might be I could not found related to this that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Azure pricing is mainly based on the consumption. So you can create as many storage accounts as you like (up to the limit per subscription which is currently 100) but only pay for the consumption in those storage accounts.

For a storage account, you pay for 3 things:

1. Amount of data stored.
2. Number of storage transactions performed against your storage account (this basically boils down to the number of REST API calls you make against a storage account).
3. Outbound bandwidth consumption. This is essentially the amount of data that flows from your storage account. However you're charged only when the data flows outside of the region where your storage account is hosted.

In Azure you're billed for your Subscription. So you will get one bill but will include charges for all the resources you consumed in that subscription.

To learn about Azure Pricing in general: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/.

To learn about Azure Storage Pricing in general: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/

To learn how storage pricing is calculated: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/

Comment: thanks for you reply. So If there are two storage account I created then If I consume storage then and then I need to pay if there is no any file uploaded then that will no need to pay right?